# Is there a similar object to session with windows form

Tags: winforms

I'm a little new to windows forms. I would like a way to persist data across my windows form application. I am using a static dictionary that I setup in my program.cs file. I do not wat to pass this data manually from form to form in the constructor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you want to have a singleton class that holds that information ...

Comment: ok so you are saying that my solution is correct? i.e. create a static dictionery.

Comment: there is allways more than one way to do stuff ... if you just want to pass data around without questioning the coding style, every solution that works is correct. if you want to make sure that there is only one instance of that data, that every form is accessing, think of a singleton... you're not really asking a well defined question here, so this is as close as it gets ... :/

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598602/declaring-global-variables-in-vb